# Google Classroom API Object Authentication

Tags: authentication, google-api

I am successfully using the Google Classroom API in the browser to act on behalf of a user who has granted permissions to do so through OAuth2 using the Google Client library. I'm trying to figure out how to trust API results sent to my server from the browser. Here's a story to explain the end-to-end problem I'm trying to solve.

1. User X logs into my website using Google Login, and I save that user's Google Login object (which is transferred to my server in the form of an id_token and decoded to ensure authenticity as described in detail [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)) in my database. That response ends up looking something like this heavily redacted object:

```js
{
   "iss": "accounts.google.com",
   "azp": "redacted-string",
   "aud": "redacted-string",
   "sub": "redacted-string",
   "hd": "redacted-string",
   "email": "redacted-string",
   "email_verified": true,
   "at_hash": "redacted-string",
   "name": "redacted-string",
   "picture": "redacted-string",
   "given_name": "redacted-string",
   "family_name": "redacted-string",
   "locale": "en",
   "iat": redacted-number,
   "exp": redacted-number,
   "jti": "redacted-string"
}
```

2. I want to do something in Google Classroom on behalf of the user, like list classrooms. So I ask for permission to do that by sending them through the appropriate OAuth2 workflow that Google provides. Then, having received consent, I make the desired Google Classrooms API call to list classrooms, and receive back a list of classrooms, something like this:

```js
{
 "courses": [
  {
   "id": "redacted-number",
   "name": "redacted-string",
   "ownerId": "redacted-number",
   "creationTime": "2019-01-09T19:04:28.084Z",
   "updateTime": "2019-01-09T19:04:56.828Z",
   "enrollmentCode": "redacted-string",
   "courseState": "DECLINED",
   "alternateLink": "https://classroom.google.com/c/redacted-string",
   "teacherGroupEmail": "redacted-string",
   "courseGroupEmail": "redacted-string",
   "teacherFolder": {
    "id": "redacted-string"
   },
   "guardiansEnabled": false
  },
  {
   "id": "redacted-number",
   "name": "redacted-string",
   "ownerId": "redacted-number",
   "creationTime": "2019-01-09T19:03:06.321Z",
   "updateTime": "2019-01-09T19:03:05.328Z",
   "enrollmentCode": "redacted-string",
   "courseState": "PROVISIONED",
   "alternateLink": "https://classroom.google.com/c/redacted-string",
   "teacherGroupEmail": "redacted-string",
   "courseGroupEmail": "redacted-string",
   "teacherFolder": {
    "id": "redacted-string"
   },
   "guardiansEnabled": false
  }
 ]
}
```

3. Now I'd like to convey this information to my server and store it in a database associated with the user. I'm using JWT already to authenticate *the user* so when the request reaches my server I know which user sent it. What I *don't* know is how to trust the Google Classroom object they are sending me actually came from Google.

Maybe I'm over-thinking it, and I shouldn't worry about a user propagating fake Google object data into my database? I would have thought the objects were signed in some way that my server might be able to verify the authenticity of the Google objects given my application credentials and the proxy user's verified Google sign-in object. I would think this process would be similar to how Google Login allows me to verify the authenticity of the sign-in on my server side.

If there's a clear way to do that, I don't see it. Can anyone help me put things into focus?

P. S. This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117586/trusting-google-api-response-objects-and-ownership#comment95108097_54117586) which never got a decent answer, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to guard against a valid user posting phony data to your server from the users client browser.

One option is to update your application to enable server-side access to Google's API.

There is documentation on how to do that here: 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access

If you have access to the Access Token from the client side requests you can also perform the following request pattern:

1) Client Makes the following HTTP request to an API endpoint on your application server

```
GET /api/list_courses HTTP/1.1
Host: yourapp.example.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer googles_api_access_token_here
```

2) The /api/list_courses endpoint on your application server makes the following request to googles API server:

```
GET /v1/courses HTTP/1.1
Host: classroom.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer googles_api_access_token_here
```

3) The response from (2) is sent back to your application server

4) your application server responds with the list of courses to the client.

Comment: The only examples I've seen of the pattern you are describing are for so-called offline behavior, where the user may not even be in the loop when the requests are made on their behalf. All things OAuth seem to be fundamentally geared toward client side interaction patterns...

Comment: yes the pattern I am describing is client -> google -> client -> server

Comment: Got it, I modified the above post to include a link on enabling server-side access to google's API. The requests must be made in the order of client -> server -> google -> server -> client.There is no way to ensure data integrity for your server with the current request pattern you are using.

This does allow for requests when the user is online or offline.

Comment: that was my intuition as well, lets wait to see what others have to say and if there is no dissent, I'll likely accept this answer. Any thoughts / ideas on how to get the bearer token established by the Google Client library out at run-time in order to pass it to my server to use it as a proxy?

Comment: During runtime, 
Looks like you can sign the user in silently to retrieve the token: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900956/silent-sign-in-to-retrieve-token-with-googleapiclient/35075234


https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

Answer (score 1):

the problem might not be a problem at all, as you've wrote:

> What I don't know is how to trust the Google Classroom object they are sending me actually came from Google.

assuming `API` communication, they are not even sending it, but you fetch it via `SSL` or `TLS` (the host's certificate can also be [validated](https://crt.sh/), while this is not required, because when it does not match the `A` record in `DNS`, it's invalid). ID tokens of the users also could be validated; see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#validatinganidtoken).

Comment: I guess I'm just surprised the Google objects aren't signed at least. My secret can know the Google API client secret,  after all, such is fundamentally unknown to the browser that made the request to Google.

Comment: @vicatcu `SSL` and `TLS` implement end-to-end encryption; as soon as the handshake succeeds, one can assume that the other side is who it claims to be. as soon as a request is being passed into the stack, one can only capture destination addresses, but no URLs. this is handled by the browser or other HTTP/S client implementation, behind the scenes.

Comment: if you want to know for certain, you could use a service account on the server-side; this requires another oAuth2 flow. when any client is involved, the data once leaves the stack and in this moment it could be modified - or played back. the client-side is the issue, not end-to-end encryption, which uses a direct connection.

Comment: the trouble is there are two independent transactions, and the whole sequence is not atomic. (1) browser to google, (2) browser to my server. If I knew second transaction was predicated on the first action I'd be fine. But whose to say the second transaction wasn't a rogue cURL execution?

Comment: @vicatcu just open Chrome or Firefox and hit `F12`, select the network tab; there one can playback any request, which is very convenient for web-development. that's why api <-> server <-> client makes sense, so that the client will never communicate directly with the API, except for obtaining the auth token; this would change the whole game, because it's twice end-to-end, with the encrypted data never leaving the stack on a hop in between.